# ggplot2 non standard evaluation

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, non-standard-evaluation

As I need to use ggplot2 in a function, non standard evaluation mode is required. Therefore, `aes_string` with `"price"` is used. However, then `..count..` no longer is defined

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes_string(x="price", ..count../sum(..count..))) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 500)
```

Comment: Give this a try: `y="..count../sum(..count..)"`

Comment: All strings or no strings, no inbetween with `aes_string()`

Comment: Thanx, this is he solution